# How to remove columns from a pre-selected dataframe which contain only NaN's

Tags: python, pandas

I want to remove all columns which contain only NaN's. This is my example code:

```
rutte2[[u'50PLUS', u'AOV', u'Bontes', u'Bontes/Van Klaveren',
       u'Brinkman', u'CD', u'CDA', u'ChristenUnie', u'D66', u'De Jong',
       u'Eerdmans/Van Schijndel', u'GPV', u'GroenLinks', u'Hendriks',
       u'Houwers', u'Klein', u'Kortenoeven/Hernandez', u'Kuzu/Öztürk',
       u'Lazrak', u'LN', u'LPF', u'Nawijn', u'Nijpels', u'PvdA', u'PvdD',
       u'PVV', u'RPF', u'SGP', u'SP', u'Unie 55+', u'Van Klaveren',
       u'Van Oudenallen', u'Van Vliet', u'Verdonk', u'Verkerk', u'VVD',
       u'Wijnschenk', u'Wilders']].dropna(axis=1, how='all')
```

When I do

```
type(rutte2[[u'50PLUS', u'AOV', u'Bontes', u'Bontes/Van Klaveren',
           u'Brinkman', u'CD', u'CDA', u'ChristenUnie', u'D66', u'De Jong',
           u'Eerdmans/Van Schijndel', u'GPV', u'GroenLinks', u'Hendriks',
           u'Houwers', u'Klein', u'Kortenoeven/Hernandez', u'Kuzu/Öztürk',
           u'Lazrak', u'LN', u'LPF', u'Nawijn', u'Nijpels', u'PvdA', u'PvdD',
           u'PVV', u'RPF', u'SGP', u'SP', u'Unie 55+', u'Van Klaveren',
           u'Van Oudenallen', u'Van Vliet', u'Verdonk', u'Verkerk', u'VVD',
           u'Wijnschenk', u'Wilders']])
```

it returns this:

```
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

Here's an image for further explanation:

[image: pandas screenshot]

Why is this not working?

Comment: `dropna` is not inplace you need to assign back or pass `inplace=True`

Comment: What do you mean with assign back?

Comment: Thanks by the way!

Comment: e.g. `df = df.dropna()` for example most pandas ops return a copy and are not in place, most accept an `inplace` arg

Comment: still didnt work though

Answer (score 0):

So "type" returns the type of the Python object which apparently in your case is a pandas Dataframe. If you want to print the dataframe use

```
print rutte2
```

or in Python 3.x.

```
print(rutte2)
```

dropna returns a new dataframe with NaN's removed. If you want to remove the NaN's from rutte2 use:

(edit: use subset to do inplace removal on selected columns)

```
rutte2.dropna(subset=[u'50PLUS', u'AOV', u'Bontes', u'Bontes/Van Klaveren',
       u'Brinkman', u'CD', u'CDA', u'ChristenUnie', u'D66', u'De Jong',
       u'Eerdmans/Van Schijndel', u'GPV', u'GroenLinks', u'Hendriks',
       u'Houwers', u'Klein', u'Kortenoeven/Hernandez', u'Kuzu/Öztürk',
       u'Lazrak', u'LN', u'LPF', u'Nawijn', u'Nijpels', u'PvdA', u'PvdD',
       u'PVV', u'RPF', u'SGP', u'SP', u'Unie 55+', u'Van Klaveren',
       u'Van Oudenallen', u'Van Vliet', u'Verdonk', u'Verkerk', u'VVD',
       u'Wijnschenk', u'Wilders'], axis=1, how='all', inplace=True)
```

Are you sure rutte2 is not an empty dataframe :-) ?

Comment: @JanKlaas are your __sure__ that the columns you want to drop contain __only__ NaNs?

Comment: Yes, and also it returns 'None' when I try to use dropna

Comment: Use subset (see edited response above), next time please include data sample and code for easier replication. Cheers